# Preview an ASP.NET .CSHTML file in XSP

Tags: asp.net, mono, asp.net-webpages, xsp

Is there a way to force XSP on Mono to parse `.cshtml` files in order to be able to only preview them before doing the routing? Could the setting be forced?

Currently, the server only forwards the file for download and does not process it.

Running latest stable version of Mono (3.12.1) on CentOS 7.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that I needn't have made a local copy of `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` assembly. By doing this, I am finally able to run `.CSHMTL` files from XSP.[image]

EDIT: To set a default `.cshtml` page add the following XML node to the `appSettings` section of the `Web.config` to give a hint to the `XSP` server:

```
<add key="MonoServerDefaultIndexFiles" value="HelloWorld.cshtml, helloworld.cshtml" />
```